Shiny reactive text causing fatal error when run on server
So I had an R Shiny dashboard that was running totally fine with no errors or warnings when run locally using RStudio. However, when deployed to a shiny server it was not working at all. The UI would load but I could see the server code was not running at all (I put lots of error logs throughout the code so I could see the server code was not running). Beyond this, there were no errors to the server Shiny logs beyond "Execution halted".
So I worked out what was causing the problem and just wanted to know why this would work locally but not when deployed.
The problem was with this part of the UI code that was causing the problem (worked out through just trial and error of commenting out sections of code):
div(id = "longitudinal_dass21",fluidRow(h4("DASS-21", style = "color: #3279b7")),
fluidRow(htmlOutput("longitudinal_severity_interpretation_k10")),
fluidRow(style = "height:450px",withSpinner(plotOutput("dass21_longitudinal"), type = 5, size = 0.3, color = "#3d90db")),
fluidRow(align = 'right', downloadButton('dass21_longitudinal_button')),
br(),
),
div(id = "longitudinal_pwi",fluidRow(h4("PWI-A", style = "color: #3279b7")),
fluidRow(htmlOutput("longitudinal_severity_interpretation_k10")),
fluidRow(style = "height:450px",withSpinner(plotOutput("pwi_longitudinal"), type = 5, size = 0.3, color = "#3d90db")),
fluidRow(align = 'right', downloadButton('pwi_longitudinal_button')),
br(),
),

More specifically, it was with this reactive text output: "longitudinal_severity_interpretation_k10" where it is used in both the different divs but the text would change dependent upon an input. The divs in the text were also hidden / shown using ShinyJS dependent upon an input and they were never shown at the same time. The reactive text was as follows:
output$longitudinal_severity_interpretation_k10 <- renderUI({
HTML(paste("The plot below shows the percentage of clients in each severity rating for each month for the ", sub('.*\\,','', Assessment_Name()),". Given that small sample sizes in each month could distort the overview of severity percentages, there is a filter on the left that allows you to only include data when the sample size in each month is greater than or equal to what you specify. Use the button below the plot to download a PNG file of the plot.<br><br>", sep=""))})

So I'm trying to work out if there is a problem with my use of the same reactive text within each div. Would this be expected to cause a fatal error when run on a server (with no error output) but run totally fine locally? I am using Shiny version 1.9.1 and ShinyJS version 2.1.0.

So when deploying to the server I can see a browser error when inspecting this section with Developer Tools. It appears that the reactive "longitudinal_severity_interpretation_k10" text has a div and id applied to it and it would appear that this needs to be unique (which it is currently not obviously) even though they were never shown at the same time because they were hidden or shown separately. However, I still don't understand why this wouldn't cause a problem (like a warning or error) when running the app locally?

The IDs in HTML must be unique.  The difference when working locally probably depends on the browser you use (instead of the RStudio preview window, or whatever).

@MichaelDewar Shiny applies the ID to htmlOutput and it uses the name of the output item. Regardless, there were no apparent errors when running the app locally in either the console (when running in the RStudio preview window) or when opening in a browser window (Chrome). When opening in Chrome (locally) you don't get an error (either in the browser or the RStudio console), but when running on a server (also using Chrome) you get a fatal error and the error reported in the browser's Developer Tools. Seems problematic that it works (or doesn't work!) like this.

If your issues are caused by duplicated IDs try enabling shiny::devmode() and you'll get client side errors.
